# Android outputs have a lot of I/Editor﹕ setup window support handles

Tags: android, editor

When I have opened up a new dialog, it has many EditText for user to input. And it is very slow and at the meantime, from the logcat, there are a lot of I/Editor﹕ setup window support handles, wondering if this is the reason why it slows down.
Could anyone tell me why my logcat has so many out put as I/Editor﹕ setup window support handles? how can I get rid of this?

Thanks